# Can Amadeus flight delay prediction API being used in China?

Tags: amadeus

I use flight delay prediction api for China domestic flight prediction. The API give an Error 500: Internal Server Error.
Here  are  my api request url given by the api documentation web page and response info.

Thanks!
Liao Chen

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/travel/predictions/flight-delay?originLocationCode=PKX&destinationLocationCode=KWE&departureDate=2021-08-11&departureTime=2021-08-11T15%3A15%3A00&arrivalDate=2021-08-11&arrivalTime=2021-08-11T18%3A15%3A00&aircraftCode=737&carrierCode=CZ&flightNumber=6188&duration=PT3H

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 141,
      "detail": "ModelError: Received server error (500) from model with message \"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>\n\". See https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/layla-all-v2 in account 740907634312 for more information.\n{\n  RespMetadata: {\n    StatusCode: 424,\n    RequestID: \"1cc2ca6d-59eb-494d-9a2c-f21c568c3346\"\n  },\n  LogStreamArn: \"arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:740907634312:log-group:/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/layla-all-v2\",\n  Message_: \"Received server error (500) from model with message \\\"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\\\">\\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\\n<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>\\n\\\". See https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/layla-all-v2 in account 740907634312 for more information.\",\n  OriginalMessage: \"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\\\">\\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\\n<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>\\n\",\n  OriginalStatusCode: 500\n}",
      "status": 500,
      "title": "UNEXPECTED ERROR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The departure and arrival times in your request have the wrong format. According to the [documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-delay-prediction/api-reference) they have to be in HH:mm:ss format.

Comment: The Error message "the date on which the traveler will arrive to the destination from the origin. Dates are specified in the ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD format, e.g. 2019-12-25" is from the web page "https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-delay-prediction/api-reference" where I use HH:mm:ss  fromat.

Comment: But in your request above I see `departureTime=2021-08-11T15%3A15%3A00`  and `arrivalTime=2021-08-11T18%3A15%3A00`, it's not a HH:mm:ss format.